# Android:How to display menu items in a grid view(normally it displayed in listview)?

Tags: android, view, menu

1. I want to display menu items in a grid view but normally it displayed in a list view.
2. Can we apply gridview to menu items?

Comment: Check it out.
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html

Comment: What, **precisely**, do you mean by "menu items". Feel free to paste in some code, or perhaps a link to a screenshot. The only thing in modern Android that would qualify as a "menu" is the action bar overflow, and I do not know if that is what you are referring to.

Comment: can u be more clrear?? what do you want.. yes we can display in grid view

Comment: if click the menu,the below items are displayed in list but i want it in grid.<menu xmlns:androclass="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">  
      
        <item  android:id="@+id/item1"  
            android:title="Item 1"/>  
      
        <item  android:id="@+id/item2"  
            android:title="Item 2"/>  
         
        <item  android:id="@+id/item3"  
            android:title="Item 3"/>  
        
    </menu>

Answer (score 1):

I presume that what you are referring to as "menu items" shown in a "list view" is the action bar overflow, shown here descending from the `...` affordance:

[image: Action Bar with Overflow]

(image courtesy of the Android Open Source Project)

You do not have control over the way these are rendered; they will be in a vertically-scrolling list.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry to say this, but you cant customize the menu in android. No source was provided by Google to customize the menu item in android, but you can add images as user2592807 suggested. Hope it helps. Thank you.